# Does SQL Server support hash partitioning?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My current database is SQL Server 2008 and will be upgrading to SQL Server 2014. I cannot confirm if SQL Server 2014 supports hash partitions. I have a single table that has about 29M records. This table is growing extremely fast. In the past year it is doubling every 3-4 months. I'd like to horizontally partition my table based on a client id. I've search online and cannot confirm they support it.

Answer (score 2):

No, SQL Server does not support hash partitioning. As Ben says, you can roll your own using a hashing function and a persisted computed column. The *only* scenario when this is recommended is when latch contention on the last page is slowing down inserts, and *no other time*. Read [Hash Partitioning, SQL Server, and Scaling Writes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/04/hash-partitioning-sql-server-scaling-writes/) for more details.

> This table is growing extremely fast. In the past year it is doubling every 3-4 months.

So, what does this have to do with hash partitioning, or with *any* partitioning? Partitioning gives no performance benefits, it purpose is data storage management. For performant access to large datasets, consider indexes. For analytic workloads, use columnstores. For general performance issues read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Kendra Little has a decent article [How To Decide if You Should Use Table Partitioning](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/).

Comment: What's the basis of your statement that it does not?

Comment: Why do you write that "Partitioning gives no performance benefits" - in Kendra's article you reference, under section 'Query Performance on Partitioned Tables' it says that if the query includes the partition key it would direct the query to only a single partition resulting in queries to perform better?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can "fake it". Specifically, if you come up with your own hashing function (say ClientID modulo «desired number of partitions»), you can use that as your partitioning key (or part of it).

Comment: You also need to a persisted computed column as the hash value.

Comment: Yes; I wasn't clear that the result of the hashing function needs to be stored as a column in the table (whether via a computed column or the less exotic "compute and update" method).

Comment: It sucks because the partition key has to be part of the clustered key but it is already *derived* from it ( taking a hash of the cluster key ) so this redundancy makes no sense, if I get this correctly

Comment: @fmi21 - that doesn't matter. I've used this technique on tables where the clustering key was an identity column (let's call it ID) and the hashing function was `ID % 256` and then changing the clustering key to (hash, ID). Why? To alleviate "last page" contention on high velocity insert tables. It adds a bit to queries (now you need to do something like `where ID = @ID and hash = @ID % 256`) but that's doable.